# Rails 3.2 update conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails model where I want to update an attribute by calculating the current value of that attribute plus the value I'm sending as a parameter.  The following will update the record and overwrite the existing value for the attribute

```
def self.mark_receipt(qty_received,client_id,product_code)
  Product.where(:client_id => client_id, :product_code => product_code)
         .update_all(:qty_on_hand => :qty_received,
                     :qty_received => qty_received)
end
```

I want something more like this, but the following syntax doesn't work.

```
def self.mark_receipt(qty_received,client_id,product_code)
  Product.where(:client_id => client_id, :product_code => product_code)
         .update_all(:qty_on_hand => :qty_on_hand + qty_received,
                     :qty_received => :qty_received + qty_received)
end
```

EDIT

Getting really close with the below answer, but this is what sql is running in the background

```
Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` 
                      WHERE `products`.`client_id` = 1 AND `products`.`product_code` = '88-89c'
  SQL (0.6ms)         UPDATE `products` 
                      SET `qty_on_hand` = 165, `qty_received` = 165
```

Instead of

```
 UPDATE `products`
 SET `qty_on_hand` = 165, `qty_received` = 165
 WHERE `products`.`client_id` = 1 AND `products`.`product_code` = '88-89c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this would work based on docs
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

```
Product.update_all(['qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand + ? , qty_received = qty_received + ?', qty_received, qty_received],
                    {:client_id => client_id, :product_code => product_code)})
```

Notice that this would make the add operation at the database.

Comment: With your answer I'm getting ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: qty_on_hand = qty_on_hand + ? , qty_received = qty_received + ?):

Comment: sorry, I just notice I forgot to add the second parameter. Try it now

Comment: That's very nice and far more railsy than what I was thinking. :D

Comment: Both answers were very helpful.  I come from a world of sql so trying to get my hands around activerecord has been a task

Comment: @MBHNYC, the problem with your implementation is that it would generate one update query for each product. With the implementation of this answer it will use only one query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're updating all and quantity on hand may change, you should cycle through the results of the where clause:

```
def self.mark_receipt(qty_received,client_id,product_code)
  Product.where(:client_id => client_id, :product_code => product_code).each do |p|
    p.update_attributes(:qty_on_hand=> p.qty_on_hand + qty_received, :qty_received => p.qty_received + qty_received)
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It works however it seems to update all records instead of only the one the condition finds.  What method do I need to only update the record that meets the criteria specified in the where clause?

Comment: With your help I'm very close.  Look at the above sql output and see where we can get from here.

Comment: small note, you don't need "Product" in there since the scope is already the Product object, just starting with "where" should work. Looking at the SQL now